# Bar translucency gone in iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7

Compare the two screenshots:

Done on iOS 7.0 simulator

[image]

And the one done on iOS 7.0.3 iPhone 4S:

[image]

Same code here and there and same stuff! Any idea why the translucency is gone on the real device?

I have this code to simulate it (I know it's probably awkward and not right but that's how it is):

```
topMenuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, TOP_BAR_ORIG_HEIGHT)];
topMenuView.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIToolbar *topMenuViewBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -4, self.view.frame.size.width, TOP_BAR_ORIG_HEIGHT + 4)];
topMenuViewBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
topMenuViewBar.barTintColor = [BSFunctions getColorFromHex:@"1ea6ff"];
const CGFloat statusBarHeight = 20;

UIView *underlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -statusBarHeight, topMenuViewBar.frame.size.width, topMenuViewBar.frame.size.height + statusBarHeight)];
[underlayView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
[underlayView setBackgroundColor:[BSFunctions getColorFromHex:@"1ea6ff"]];
[underlayView setAlpha:0.36f];
[topMenuViewBar insertSubview:underlayView atIndex:1];
UIView *underlayView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -statusBarHeight, topMenuViewBar.frame.size.width, topMenuViewBar.frame.size.height + statusBarHeight)];
[underlayView2 setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
[underlayView2 setBackgroundColor:[BSFunctions getColorFromHex:@"0291ff"]];
[underlayView2 setAlpha:0.36f];
[topMenuViewBar insertSubview:underlayView2 atIndex:2];
[topMenuView addSubview:topMenuViewBar];
[self.view addSubview:topMenuView];
```

The main point is it **used to work before** on the device! But after iOS 7.0.3 came out it changed. I'm noticing the same behavior in Facebook and Fitocracy iOS apps.

**UPDATE**

On Xcode 5.0.1 with iOS 7.0.3 simulator we have this (which is different from the first image on iOS 7.0 simulator as you can see):

[image]

Comment: Have you turned off the motion and stuff in accessibility in your iPhone?

Comment: As Fogmeister suggested, check settings for [Accessibility > Increase Contrast](http://www.macworld.com/article/2048738/get-to-know-ios-7-changes-in-the-settings-app.html), which reduces translucency.

Comment: @Fogmeister No, no changes whatsoever were made. And I think there's no such option on the simulator.

Comment: Also, Apple uses [less translucency on iPhone 4](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/09/new-lease-on-life-or-death-sentence-ios-7-on-the-iphone-4/) because of its less powerful hardware. You said iPhone 4S, so nope, I guess that's not the problem for you.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yeah, that's what I meant. Tested on iPhone 5 as well. Same thing there.

Comment: Same on 5S too, not a hardware restriction. The blur has gone and the tint colour is a whole lot different :( Also the case with tab and tool bars

Comment: @Mutix think it's a bug? The funny thing is that users on iOS 7 versions prior to iOS 7.0.3 have the old style

Comment: I don't know to be honest. There's a thread in the apple dev forums, and someone has filed a radar to find out more. Worth keeping an eye on it https://devforums.apple.com/thread/210495?tstart=0

Comment: Our app is experiencing the same thing. We are working to correct. Will update when we figure it out. (It's impacting the FB app as well)

Comment: I am having the same problem with my app. About to play with some code to see if maybe Apple just changed the way the API worked (not like Apple, but who knows)

Comment: Have been playing around with different colors and settings in storyboards etc, and have not found a way to give bars the pre 7.0.3 appearance. Even when setting the bars to opaque, the barTintColor doesn't come out the same as expected (RGB values displayed on the screen are not the same as the RGB colors set in the appearance).

Comment: My app just got approved and is pending developer release, but it looks quite ugly with the wrong nav and tab bar colors without the blur and the app store screenshots don't represent what it now looks like. I don't know if I wait to hear more info to release it or if I pull it completely and submit another version with solid colored bars and no transparency. There isn't anything in the release notes or changelog either regarding this. Pretty annoyed right now!

Comment: I can indeed confirm Apple changed the translucency behavior. Compare http://t.co/LP8NHe5wuP (7.0.2) http://t.co/KWZlKPcR3c (7.0.3). Both screenshots from an iPhone 5S

Comment: Is anyone also seeing the issue that I've posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368488/ios-7-1-uinavigationbar-image

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, so after having played around with the colours a bit more, I managed to get a similar sort of appearance with the blur!

Previously, I was setting a barTintColor on the navigation bar appearance which had the following values:

R:17
G:63
B:95
A:1

This was fine in iOS < 7.0.3, and the output color in the nav bar (with the blur effect) was actually:

R:62
G:89
B:109

Since iOS 7.0.3, the barTintColor seems to take into account the alpha value of the color we set. This meant that the nav bar was actually outputting a solid color 17,63,95, and there was no blur effect.

The key to getting the blur effect back is setting an alpha < 1 in the barTintColor.

After lots of guess work and trying different RGB values, I managed to get the exact same RGB output from the nav (and tab) bar, using the following RGBA:

R:4.5
G:61.6
B:98
A:0.65

It does not look like there's a magic ratio to apply to the previous color to obtain the new one.

Anyway I've actually rejected the binary that got approved this afternoon, and have re-submitted with these new values so that user's don't get an ugly app :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So are you actually getting a blur effect with this? We just get a translucent view when we change the alpha of the barTintColor...

Comment: There is a blur effect yes. I found alpha values between 0.5 and 0.7 seemed to give the best blur results. I will update my post with screenshots shortly.

Comment: Ok the alpha color does change things, but moving the blur view around causes really bad flicker

Comment: How about the compatibility with versions of iOS 7 prior to iOS 7.0.3? Should we like keep two versions of the code?

Comment: @SergiusGee On iOS 7.0.2, the color is not quite the same (nearly though) but the blur effect is still present. I imagine the uptake of 7.0.3 is / will be pretty fast, I wouldn't worry about the appearance in pre 7.0.3.

Comment: bear in mind you can change the barStyle too, I've found I can sometimes get a better effect using UIBarStyleBlack, depending on the colour I'm trying to blur. I really hope they put it back to how it was in 7.0.4, and then leave it alone! But since this is undocumented functionality, they can do whatever they like, so I'm not holding my breath!

Comment: @Sam turns out they didn't put it back in 7.0.4. And my guess is that they never will! So we should just forget about it ever existed.

Comment: And it appears to have changed again in iOS 7.1