# Potential Memory leak when detecting device information

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having a memory leak in the code below but don't really know how to fix it. I tried making machine = nil; but that didn't work. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"] || [platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])
            [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:0.9];
machine = nil;
```

I get the leak in stringWithCSString:machine: `potential leak of memory pointed to by 'machine'`.

Comment: BTW - curious why you need a different tint color just for these 4 devices?

Comment: @rmaddy Well I have seening a different translucent/alpha changes from iOS7.0.1-iOS7.0.3. So I am trying to neutralize it as much as possible and it seems that iPhone4 treats iOS7.0.3 translucency like iOS7.0.1. I believe Apple made some changes because of the NavigationBar with AppleMaps, they used to force translucent navigation bars dark grey. Have you had any trouble with Translucency Tool Bars? Or Apple Maps.

Comment: @rmaddy Here is a post on what I'm talking about if you want to read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534473/bar-translucency-gone-in-ios-7-0-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calls to `malloc` need to be paired with calls to `free`.

Change `machine = nil` to `free(machine)`.

BTW - your code be made a lot easier:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname si;
uname(&si);
if (strcmp(si.machine, "iPhone3,1") == 0 || strcmp(si.machine, "iPhone3,2") == 0 || strcmp(si.machine, "iPhone3,3") == 0 || strcmp(si.machine, "iPhone4,1") == 0) {
}
```

No need for the memory management or creating `NSString` objects.

Comment: What does utsname do and uname do? What exactly is that? Thanks, this is new information to me.

Comment: These do exactly what your code does but in a much simpler way. `uname` is a C function.