# iOS 7 navigation bar transculent feature running different for each subversion of iOS 7

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I'm developing an iOS application.
I'm using navigationbar with transculent property is true.

But same code is running difference for each iOS 7 subversion.
For iOS 7.0: alpha like 0.6 ( Semi-transparent )
For iOS 7.0.4: alpha like 0.3 ( fully-transparent )

Is this iOS bug ? How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue which to the best of my knowledge has not been fixed yet.
Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534473/bar-translucency-gone-in-ios-7-0-3) and [here](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/210495) for some more discussion on the subject.
In my own app I had to set different alpha values for different iOS 7 versions.